# Expressing $``\!\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n,n)\!"$ without losing information?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, terminology, infinity

Consider the sequence
$\{(n,n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$ $(n,n)\to(\infty,\infty)$ as $n\to\infty$, but "$(\infty,\infty)$'' loses the information that the terms of $(n,n)$ remain equal $\forall n$. This is contrast to the sequence
$\{(n,n^n)\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}, $ where $(n,n^n)\to(\infty,\infty)$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^n}=0$.

**Question:** I want to *parsimoniously* express $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n,n)$ in a way that preserves the information that both terms of this double stay equal as $n\to\infty$. Is $``\!\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n,n)\!"$ the most *succinct* way this can be done?

Comment: Well, the value of a limit describes the destination, not how you arrived at it. You could look at the real projective plane, I suppose, where the points corresponding to $(n,n,1)$ converge to $(1,1,0),$ but every sequence on a line of slope $1$ going to infinity converges to that point. $(n,\sqrt{n^2-1},1)$ also goes to that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Losing the information that two elements are the same, or more generally are not independent, is indeed a common problem. E.g. when taking into account computation error, or observation error, adding the error margins is valid only when variables are independent. $x-x$ has no error at all.

This problem occurs every time an element is replaced by a class of equivalence - here you mentioned equivalence at $+\infty$. For example the pointer aliasing problem in computer science is another - quite remote - example.

The most precise thing one can do is to keep elements in a symbolic form (in a form that uniquely identifies them) as long as possible. I.e. keeping $n,n$ this way, or $f(n), f(n)$.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! They were very helpful. It sounds like "$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (n,n)" is a decent way to prevent the aforementioned information loss. For Thomas's comment I will look into how the real projective plane can be used, I'm unfamiliar (or have forgotten about) that concept.